# grep -v removing lines but adding back blank lines in stdout

Tags: bash, grep

I'm running a browser test which generates a lot of javascript errors which are unimportant to me, such as:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the script 'https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
```

I'm filtering the lines with grep -v like so:

```
cucumber | grep -v 'Report Only'
```

This is removing the line as expected, but it is adding a blank line. This separates each interesting line of my test by 10-20 lines, which is cause a big readability problem.

Any idea why grep -v is somehow replacing the pattern with a blank line?

Comment: Upload output of `cucumber` somewhere and add link to your question.

Comment: What newline? Is it a linefeed or a cariage-return? Are you sure that the empty lines are not also in the output (`grep '^$'` to see the output)?

Comment: Workaround for suppressing empty lines: `cucumber 2>&1 | grep -v 'Report Only' | grep .` (last character of command is a dot).

Comment: Maybe there really are empty lines in the output. `grep -Ev 'Report Only|^$'` should get rid of them too.

Comment: @WalterA interesting, when I add ```| grep .``` I get nothing at all :P  . Probably a clue to the root issue though.

Comment: @alvits that fixes it +1